# Can I add arbitrary config to a pod spec deployed with a helm chart without modifying the Helm chart?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

I'm using this Helm chart to deploy: https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/atlantis

It deploys this stateful set: https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/atlantis/templates/statefulset.yaml

Is there a way I can add arbitrary config values to a pod spec that was deployed with a Helm chart without having to modify the chart? For example I want to add an env: var that gets its value from a secret to the pod spec of the stateful set this chart deploys

Can I create my own Helm chart that references this Helm chart and add to the config of the pod spec? again without modifying the original chart?

EDIT: what I'm talking about is adding an env var like this:

```
env:
- name: GET_THIS_VAR_IN_ATLANTIS
  valueFrom:
    secretKeyRef:
      name: my-secret
      key: abc
```

Maybe I can create another chart as a parent of this chart and override the entire `env:` block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should have marked the previous answer as the answer but things have changed in helm3.

While there is still no built-in way of patching a chart there is now builtin support for a "post renderer" https://helm.sh/docs/topics/advanced/

So, calling kustomize as a post renderer would probably be what most would suggest now with helm3

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way I can add arbitrary config values to a pod spec that was deployed with a helm chart without having to modify the chart?

You can only make changes that the chart itself supports.

If you look at the StatefulSet definition you linked to, there are a lot of `{{ if .Values.foo }}` knobs there.  This is an fairly customizable chart and you probably can change most things.  As a chart author, you'd have to explicitly write all of these conditionals and macro expansions in.

> For example I want to add an env: var that gets its value from a secret to the pod spec of the stateful set this chart deploys

This very specific chart contains a block

```
{{- range $key, $value := .Values.environment }}
- name: {{ $key }}
  value: {{ $value | quote }}
{{- end }}
```

so you could write a custom Helm YAML values file and add in

```
environment:
  arbitraryKey: "any fixed value you want"
```

and then use the `helm install -f` option to supply that option when you install the chart.

This chart does not support injecting environment values from secrets, beyond a half-dozen specific values it supports by default (*e.g.*, GitHub tokens).

As I say, this isn't generic at all: this is very specific to what this specific chart supports in its template expansions.

Comment: thanks Im new to helm and you have confirmed my suspicions. I think the official chart is overly parameterized and not very flexible for some configs but I dont want to maintain my own copy. But can I write my own helm chart that is a parent chart of this one and override the whole `env:` block?